# iOS ReactNative build failed on M1 mac

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, apple-m1

I created a sample ReactNative project using npx react-native “projectName” on M1 chip based Mac. Project created without any issue and android project build and ran successfully without any error on both google preview emulator and real device. However iOS build gets fail. I have installed cocoa pods using Rosetta and and installed other required packages and softwares such as home-brew, watchman, Xcode, iOS emulator..etc

But if I create an expo project it works fine without any issue on both iOS and android, However I want to know, ReactNative CLI based projects works fine on M1 chipset, If it does work then, then something might be wrong with the my development setup.

Please be kind enough to help me with this issue

This is the log file data

> Blockquote
> 0 verbose cli [
> 0 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
> 0 verbose cli   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
> 0 verbose cli   'exec',
> 0 verbose cli   '--',
> 0 verbose cli   'react-native',
> 0 verbose cli   'run-ios'
> 0 verbose cli ]
> 1 info using npm@7.4.0
> 2 info using node@v15.6.0
> 3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
> 4 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 2ms
> 5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
> 6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
> 7 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
> 8 timing config:load:file:/Users/vihagayohan/Desktop/ReactNative/Ikman/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
> 9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
> 10 timing config:load:file:/Users/vihagayohan/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
> 11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
> 12 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
> 13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
> 14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
> 15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
> 16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 0ms
> 17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
> 18 timing config:load Completed in 6ms
> 19 verbose npm-session b605b9422c99c9ad
> 20 timing npm:load Completed in 15ms
> 21 timing command:exec Completed in 71201ms
> 22 verbose stack Error: command failed
> 22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
> 22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:379:20)
> 22 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1065:16)
> 22 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:296:5)
> 23 verbose pkgid Ikman@0.0.1
> 24 verbose cwd /Users/vihagayohan/Desktop/ReactNative/Ikman
> 25 verbose Darwin 20.1.0
> 26 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "react-native" "run-ios"
> 27 verbose node v15.6.0
> 28 verbose npm  v7.4.0
> 29 error code 1
> 30 error path /Users/vihagayohan/Desktop/ReactNative/Ikman
> 31 error command failed
> 32 error command sh -c react-native "run-ios"
> 33 verbose exit 1
> 0 verbose cli [
> 0 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
> 0 verbose cli   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
> 0 verbose cli   'exec',
> 0 verbose cli   '--',
> 0 verbose cli   'react-native',
> 0 verbose cli   'run-ios'
> 0 verbose cli ]
> 1 info using npm@7.4.0
> 2 info using node@v15.6.0
> 3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
> 4 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 2ms
> 5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
> 6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
> 7 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
> 8 timing config:load:file:/Users/vihagayohan/Desktop/ReactNative/Ikman/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
> 9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
> 10 timing config:load:file:/Users/vihagayohan/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
> 11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
> 12 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
> 13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
> 14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
> 15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
> 16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 0ms
> 17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
> 18 timing config:load Completed in 6ms
> 19 verbose npm-session b605b9422c99c9ad
> 20 timing npm:load Completed in 15ms
> 21 timing command:exec Completed in 71201ms
> 22 verbose stack Error: command failed
> 22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
> 22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:379:20)
> 22 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1065:16)
> 22 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:296:5)
> 23 verbose pkgid Ikman@0.0.1
> 24 verbose cwd /Users/vihagayohan/Desktop/ReactNative/Ikman
> 25 verbose Darwin 20.1.0
> 26 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "react-native" "run-ios"
> 27 verbose node v15.6.0
> 28 verbose npm  v7.4.0
> 29 error code 1
> 30 error path /Users/vihagayohan/Desktop/ReactNative/Ikman
> 31 error command failed
> 32 error command sh -c react-native "run-ios"
> 33 verbose exit 1

Thank You,
Yohan[image]

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question few days back and struggling to get a solution. So right now i have found a solution but don't know whether it's a perfect solution but so far it works fine. So basically what I did was i commented (as shown in the picture) flipper dependencies from pod file and pod install again[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude arm64 build architecture for both Pods and Project Target.

Answer (score 0):

I run react native iOS on my macbook Pro with Chip M1, i got build error. But, after follow this post, i successfully running react native iOS on macbook Pro M1. The tricks is to use Rosetta and applied it to your terminal and also XCode.
full guide follow here: [solve react native build failed on macbook Pro with chip M1](https://dev.to/handipriyono/solve-react-native-build-failed-on-m1-macbook-pro-air-2fo4)

Answer (score 0):

I just add these in Build settings > Search paths > Library search paths.

```
$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift
```

Change/Add/Replace this line in your Podfile.

```
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
```

Define this function in your Podfile
Define find-and-replace function

```
 def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
   Dir[dir].each do |name|
       text = File.read(name)
       replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
       replaced = text.index(replacestr)
       if replaced == nil && text != replace
           puts "Fix: " + name
           File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
           STDOUT.flush
       end
   end
   Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
 end
```

Then call this function from the post-install so we will need to add the following 2 function calls inside post_install do |installer|

```
find_and_replace("Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
                  "atomic_notify_one(state)", "folly::atomic_notify_one(state)") 
find_and_replace("Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
 "atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)", "folly::atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)")
```

Run `pod repo update` inside the ios folder

And update your project pods using

```
pod install
```

DONE !!